# A plea to reopen

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

Pardon me if this isn't proper etiquette, but I'm not sure where to politic for votes, so when in doubt, meta.

[This question of mine](https://serverfault.com/questions/177500/what-creative-sysadmin-resumes-have-you-seen-made-closed) was closed as off topic. Perhaps I could have framed it better for more useful responses, but its a bit annoying to see it closed.

Why you should vote to reopen:

- its relevant to the career of system administration
- it's got plenty of upvotes and only one downvote
- subjective questions are part of a healthy community
- awesome anecdotes are interesting
- five people favorited the question

Thoughts? Votes?

Answer (score 3):

The fact that you want help writing a resume to get a job as a sysadmin does not make it a suitable subject for Server Fault.

A resume is as much related to system administration as the method we use to travel to and from work. Should we then also allow discussing about various makes and models of cars, buses, trains, bicycles, etc.? How about some in depth analysis of what I might have for lunch tomorrow? After all, that is very much part of my day as a professional system administrator.

Comment: I think you're dramatically oversimplifying. There are things that are unique to system administration that can be communicated in a resume format. Furthermore, telecommuting seems like on topic... http://serverfault.com/search?q=telecommute

Comment: I think what John is trying to say is that it's not part of your "daily job", and is very open to discussion; where this site is more specifically aimed at Q&A, not discussions.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a HUGE market for a career/resume stackexchange site.  Honestly, if I weren't so tied up with projects, I'd probably look into getting it started.  That being said, the question (sadly enough, because I have a mountain of commentary on the topic!) is not in any way unique to SF, and doesn't really fit as a sysadmin question with a specific answer.

Comment: http://careeroverflow.com/ -- the site was started with the original model.

Comment: Ha!  Thanks, I should've known.  :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that topics of relevance to the professional are not well received here.  If they are well formed and useful, I think they belong.  In fact, I wish there were more along the lines.

Topics that I find of value:

- Managing a professional IT career
- Managing an IT department
- Workflow for proper operation of an IT department
- Best practices from an administrative perspective that are not necessarily technical.

These topics are of unusual value to someone as identified within the scope of the FAQ:

> system administrators and IT
>   professionals, people who manage or
>   maintain computers in a professional
>   capacity

There's plenty of information about the proper formatting of fstab, such as the manpage.  Whereas resources specifically relating professional IT are more limited.

In short, I agree.  While your question is pushing a "list question," I think there is some value there.  You have my vote.

Comment: I agree with your interpretation of the FAQ, however it seems that others interpret it to mean questions that a SysAdmin would ask in the course of their job (which generally precludes job-hunting)(just making an observation). The question does lean toward discussion however, rather than Q&A. It's a fuzzy line sometimes.